# What contract(s) for a punishment

Tags: united-states, contract-law

When I refer to punishment contract I am referring to a punishment for after someone loses a game and or another scenario. Basically there is two to three people. Person one is the person that is getting the punishment and person two is a witness and the one that is basically in control of it all aka can issue commands or have him so stuff according to the contract or agreement or whatever it would be called. And person three is optional but they would be a witness.

I can provide more information if needed.

Also what type of lawyer could help me with this.

Extra details: This is basically between two people cause the first is the one issuing it and the other is the one it is directed towards and possibly a third witness but it's mostly gonna be between two people. And it will be kind of a private thing aka anyone in the contract can't talk about anything in the Contract and about it. I believe that's a nda but not 100 percent sure. And person one can refuse to do something if it can cause a injuries(s).

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  If it's "how do I write such a contract?" that would be too broad/asking for specific legal advice (which we don't allow here).  Also, I almost hesitate to ask, but what type of punishment are you trying to exact here?

Comment: The type of lawyer you'd need for this is a contracts lawyer, by the way.

Comment: I for one don't understand the question. The whole description is too confusing.

Comment: There is no punishment i kinda just wanna know what contracts would be needed for this. I am not personally gonna do anything. I should have clarified what the persons contract is about basically it is between him and his girlfriend and he has to be barefoot 24/7 and is not allowed to wear socks and also can't wear shoes but can wear sandals if required aka if a store requires it.

Answer (score 2):

### Only governments can punish people

A contract that purportedly allowed one person to "punish" another would be void (unenforceable) for public policy reasons.

Comment: I know what I am thinking about is possible for normal people to do but I don't know what to call it or anything cause the person that is doing it has a nda or another form of that and can't tell me. And I don't know what other world's to say that would explain it better.

Comment: The person that is doing kind of what I am looking for has mentioned "very strict power of attorney" and "very strict third party" the source for these are publicly availabilie.

Comment: A contract could certainly include a penalty clause, which would in effect allow an individual to "punish" someone by invoking government power (via a lawsuit) to enforce the contract's terms and/or collect damages.  That said, I have a sneaking suspicion that this contract is likely to be invalid for other reasons (especially depending on what the "punishment" is).

Comment: @RyanM No. A contract can include rights and obligations and liquidated damages but not penalties. You may think that paying damages “penalizes” but it doesn’t - it restores the person to the position they would have been in but for your breach.

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better explanation of the meaning that I was attempting to convey (that is, that there might be "punishments" in the colloquial sense, but only in the form of enforced compliance or damages).

Comment: The persons contract is between him and his girlfriend and he has to be barefoot 24/7 and cannot wear shoes but can wear sandals when required like for example going into a store where it is required. I need to find out what contract(s) would be needed for that. Chase I wanna do something kind of similar and knowing what he did would be a good starting point.

Comment: Know there is a clause in the contract

Comment: Spot on correct answer. Pretty much a universal rule in all common law countries. Derivative contracts, insurance contracts and gambling contracts (only sometimes enforceable) can look superficially similar but the negative consequence to the person obligated to pay is based upon a third party's actions or independent event, not a breach of agreement or outcome of a contest between the parties. If @Matthew has examples of real world uses of what he thinks is analogous it might be possible to analyze it. Matthew's objective is fundamentally not legally enforceable.

Comment: I know that what I want is not possible but I know someone did something kinda similar and I would like to know what contracts but he has a nda or something similar and cannot say. I am not gonna do it cause you don't even need a contract to do it. So If I was gonna do it I would not be asking here I just want to know what it would be the he used in the begging.

Comment: Honestly when I have time I might make a new one asking about what contract he used and providing links and stuff for when he said anything. Or ask a contract lawyer it's not important enough though to pay for a lawyer.